# RedisQueue working running with a Flask Application

Tags: python, redis, flask

I'm trying to use RedisQueue as simple way to run async job processing from my application.

However, when the worker tries to run a job in the flask application, its barfing about running outside of the app context i.e. `working outside of application context`

Answer (score 1):

```
def your_task():
    with app.test_request_context():
        #your code
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense - however, excuse my ignorance but how do I get a reference to the app in the first place? something like: `app = flask.Flask(__name__)` ?

Comment: well you have you app in some place in your application. just import it from there